# Missing "Log In With The Facebook App" when using ios Facebook SDK login

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-login

I have a question regarding ios Facebook SDK login process.

Just noticed that when I try to login into my app with facebook, Safari web browser is not detecting my installed Facebook app. 

 [Only one of the devices did get screen like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfKZ1.png). 
 [On all other devices there is always juat a notification to download facebook app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1vr8.jpg). 
 I'm testing my facebook login on a real device. I'm also login in into my facebook app. 
 Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess the second Image device is an iOS 10 device and the first device is an iOS 8  device.

Comment: i get the second image also on ios10.

Comment: In the first screenShot on clicking the login with app button the Facebook app does not open rather a web view opens.

Comment: if my facebook app is installed the first image should appear after i click login with facebook inside my app. right? but it doesn't. the second image appears. and that's the issue... why the first screenshoot  is not appearing on all the devices if facebook app is instaled?

Comment: This issue is due to change in the Facebook SDK I also had to face the same problem and that is the way Facebook SDK now works.

Comment: I can see the first page on iOS 10  devices. so it is not a issue with iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

it's just a basic login permission. how can i test "Log In With Facebook App" button from login if SDK does not show it?

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"] fromViewController:controller handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error");
            } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                 NSLog(@"isCancelled");
            } else {
              NSLog(@"got data");
            }
        }];
```